# If every kind of product is monopolized by just one company (per product type), which would be the most influencial?

Tags: society, alternate-reality

I thought of a world-wide society, where every kind of product is monopolized and thus sold by just one company (per product type).

- So, for every kind of meat, there is only one company owning all of it. Same for vegetables, fish, etc.
- There is another company monopolizing everything that belongs to military.
- Another company is the only one to decide, which news arrive which people.

And so on.

Now imagine there is a council of the most influential politicians of the world, ruling it of course. This council allows but one businessman among them. This businessman has to be the director of the most influencing company of the world. And he has a veto right, if he completely dislikes something.

"Do that, and we will immediately stop selling our product."... leaving the world completely without it.

There is no forcing between the companies. If one says it shuts down, it does, and none other will replace it. So the military can't something like "Do your thing or we'll hurt you." It wouldn't work.

Which company, or which type of product would be the most influential under these conditions?

I would guess it's one of the examples above, but is that true? I could also think of the electricity owner, or water, or clothes, or cars...

Comment: What you are talking about is called a [monopoly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monopoly) in economy.

Comment: So basically nothing but super monopolies.  It will be the companies supplying the most important raw material, specifically oil, steel, and water. Although if the entire military is one company, that one company can force the others to do whatever it wants.

Comment: Your scheme has very little chance to realize. If a company holding something vital (e.g.: water) stops selling it how long would it take before they are forced to? About military: who sells guns (and ammunition, fuel, vehicles, etc.) to them? What would prevent "other" large companies to stock enough "water" (or whatever) to last years? In real world all companies will fight hard to maintain *at least* two providers for each needed "part" (see what happened when Navteq (maps provider) almost managed to obliterate its only concurrent: Teleatlas).

Comment: How wide or narrow you are willing to define "types"? Your example with military makes me ask - what about police force? So we have two companies supplying guns, one to military and other to police? Or just one? Then, there are underpants that are part of the uniform... and so on

Comment: Wouldn't that level of isolate specialism make some products pretty difficult to produce, given companies in our world are largely diversified, and thus so are facilities to produce various things at once?

Comment: I know you said one company can't force another if the other decided to stop doing its thing, but.... why can't they?  The most important products are going to be the ones we need for survival, and if one of those shuts down, *why wouldn't* the military eventually intercede?  It seems completely unbelievable that everyone else in the world would just lie down and die rather than try to force a vital product back into production.

Comment: Any company that follows through on that threat is dead, because they will see one of two reactions - either bloody war to eliminate them/turn the whatever back on, because people won't die without a fight, or their utter dissolution as unnecessary, as people re-learn how to make their own or do without, as people can and have survived with only what can be made by hand.  As a threat, it's kinda hollow.

Answer (score 2):

> Now imagine there is a council of the most influential politicians of the world, ruling it of course. This council allows but one businessman among them. This businessman has to be the director of the most influencing company of the world. And he has a veto right, if he completely dislikes something.

Well, no, it wouldn't be like this.

They're going to be chosen by the other (and possibly the military) as the one who is seen as the least likely to damage their interests and to be least opposed by everyone else.

This is, in fact, no different from the selection of a leader in a single party state.

What you're also omitting here is *how* people get to be in charge of a monopoly.  It makes a big difference.

If they're *elected* in some way (e.g. elected by lesser managers from their own group) that's different from if they're just the eldest son or daughter of the last person in charge.  It changes how they view their role, responsibilities and how they make decisions.

And most fundamentally, it controls how they choose a leader and why.  An elected official is not going to make a decision on the same principles as a monarch.

What these monopolies are is a federation of *dependent* states.  They cannot act independently (like a nation state can), but will depend on all the other groups to supply them or distribute for them.

It's an economy.

And inevitably someone would seek to have total control of it all.

And to avoid that happening you also need to have a legal and police (and military) framework in which that can't happen.

So this won't be as simple as "one man, one veto".

> "Do that, and we will immediately stop selling our product."... leaving the world completely without it.
>
> There is no forcing between the companies. If one says it shuts down, it does, and none other will replace it. So the military can't something like "Do your thing or we'll hurt you." It wouldn't work.

And how long before this person dies ?  Because they're dead and just haven't stopped moving if they say this.  The sole reason their workforce (and their families) will keep them alive is because they're providing paid work.  Stop that work and you've what's known as a revolution on your hands.  Stop that work and *other* monopolies will also experience knock-on effects.

As this person will also be conflicting with the military, police and the rest of the monopolies, they will have no support and are finished.

And they'll have an even shorter life expectancy if they're supplying the military and decide to stop !

And there's no getting around it : the military are going to be the people who not only keep you in power, but take you out of power if they decide to.

The only way to deal with that is that every monopoly has it's own military.  And that's just going to create chaos, especially as some leaders will try and merge and acquire other monopolies.

So the military, for stability, has to be independent of the monopolies in terms of appointments and internal organization.  Likewise the police and judiciary.  And although you may be able to influence these group to some extent, they're simply groups with their own agendas - they can only be pushed so far, unless you run an absolute dictatorship.

So ...

> Which company, or which type of product would be the most influential under these conditions?

None of them.

In practice this will depend on the political ability of each leader.  One time they may elect a compromise candidate to be president, to calm things down.  Another they may want a strong candidate to change things, or a weak one because they can't agree and fear giving even the slightest power to another group.

If we take the UN as an example we might expect that, despite any differences, the priority will be to choose a candidate with considerable diplomatic skills.  Think of them as dependent states who bicker and compete for scarce resources.  Managing them is a job for a skilled diplomat.

They might even operate a system like the UN for that reason.  Leaders of monopolies won't directly represent themselves in the council, but will appoint skilled diplomats to do that for them.  Why use any other system ?

Answer (score 1):

Those products that are highest in demand with the lowest elasticity.
Here is a list of low elastic demand products. (Elasticity is a measure of how much you need a product vs simply want it)

https://www.quora.com/What-are-examples-of-goods-that-have-a-very-low-elasticity-of-demand

If this veto power is an old one then steel is most likely. Due to its long term history of low elasticity especially in regards to warfare.

Some further options are gas/transportation, food, and healthcare. However if every food type has a different producer they in effect have direct competitors.